# How to install jdk with yum on Fedora 17?

Tags: linux, jdk, fedora, yum

I want to install jdk by yum on Federa 17 and using :

```
su -c 'yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk'
```

But it show "no available package". How can I do to install it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the last JDK version here: [Java SE Development Kit 7 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)
2. Choose the version jdk-7u5-linux-x64.rpm (the last one!) (*.**rpm** is the important here!) and then just type:

   ```
   user@machine#: yum localinstall jdk-7u5-linux-x64.rpm
   ```

And that is it!

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: I'm sorry, but TODAY, with Fedora 28, THIS DOES NOT WORK! Running the modern equivalent installs something called a JDK but it DOES NOT HAVE "javac"! WTF?! That's why I came to ask this question: How The Heck Do I Get A REAL JDK?

Answer (score 7):

If you really **want version 1.6 of OpenJDK for Fedora 17** you could use the one provided by Fedora 16. Use this command:

```
yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk --releasever=16 --nogpgcheck
```

(`--nogpgcheck` because `yum` complains of not having the key for Fedora 16, maybe there are better ways to solve this)

But this shows, that `java-1.7.0-openjdk` obsoletes `java-1.6.0-openjdk` and skips installation. And it shows that the package `xorg-x11-fonts-Type1` is needed. So I did

```
yum install xorg-x11-fonts-Type1
```

and then I used the openjdk package which `yum` downloaded but refused to install because of the *obsoletes warning*

```
rpm --nodeps -ihv /var/cache/yum/x86_64/16/updates/packages/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-68.1.11.5.fc16.x86_64.rpm
```

(`--nodeps` for overriding the *obsoletes warning*)

Now I have both java 1.6 and java 1.7 on my system. Java 1.7 is my default. And Java 1.6 is in `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java`.

PS: **There won't be any conflicts** when you install both 1.7 and 1.6. The reason for removing 1.6 from Fedora 17 was, that OpenJDK6 will [no longer get security updates after November 2012](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.redhat.fedora.general/414703).

Answer (score 2):

Type the following in a command prompt to install the latest version:

```
sudo yum install java
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (CentOS), I had to download it from orracle ([jdk](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)), then use rpm instead of yum. 
I found most of it [here](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-7-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)
First I did

```
  rpm -ivh jdk-7u51-linux-i586.rpm
```

And then checked that it was installed

```
 /usr/java/latest/jre/bin/java -version
```

Then added it to alternatives

```
## java ##
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/latest/jre/bin/java 200000
## javaws ##
alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/java/latest/jre/bin/javaws 200000

## Java Browser (Mozilla) Plugin 32-bit ##
alternatives --install /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so libjavaplugin.so /usr/java/latest/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so 200000

## Java Browser (Mozilla) Plugin 64-bit ##
alternatives --install /usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so libjavaplugin.so.x86_64 /usr/java/latest/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so 200000

## Install javac only if you installed JDK (Java Development Kit) package ##
alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/latest/bin/javac 200000
alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/java/latest/bin/jar 200000
```

Then you have to actually set the alternatives to point to it e.g. make sure you do

```
 alternatives --config java
 alternatives --config javac
```

etc and that the new jdk is selected.